# Intuitive explanation for Rabi oscillations in a two-level system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, two-level-system, rabi-model

Is there an intuitive explanation of why the Rabi oscillations with frequency $\Omega$ occur in a two-level systemand why they get faster when the transition dipole moment $M$ ($M\propto V$) gets larger or/and when the frequency of the light $\omega$ is not near the transition frequency $\omega_0$?
$$\Omega=\sqrt{V^2+(\omega_0-\omega)^2}$$

Comment: These lectures notes by David Pritchard and Wolfgang Ketterle (yet posted online by Cal Tech, not M.I.T.) show in detail how the Rabi oscillations are analogous to the classical time evolution by precession of a magnetic moment in an external field.  You may find them useful.  https://copilot.caltech.edu/documents/16894/chapter1.pdf

Comment: See Fermi’s Golden Rule. This will show exactly where the Rabi oscillation comes from and the dipole moment effect.

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely. Rabi's oscillations are a specific result based on Schroedinger's time-dependent equation, which is anything but intuitive.